# Report ignores default value for parameter

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-online

I createa a SSRS report for my dynamics crm, which has a couple of parameters of type boolean.

I've set the default value to "false" - and in the preview in the Business Intelligence Studio everything looks finde.

However, when I publish the report to my crm and start the report from within the crm, the report viewer defaults to the value "true" instead of "false".

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default Values for Parameter not Working in SSRS 2008 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102950/default-values-for-parameter-not-working-in-ssrs-2008-r2)

Comment: not quite as I don't have the settings-menu for the report because I added the report to crm-online and not to a standard SSRS-server

Answer (score 4):

Doh!

I designed the report with an english version of the BIDS - while my report in crm-online is shown in german!

When I set the default-value for the parameter to "false" this works for english, but not for germanm, as the default value in german should be "nein" (for boolean values). Obviously the default-value is matched to the string-representation of the boolean-value for false, which is obviously localized!

Instead I changed the default-value to be "=false", which is an expression and is ... well false in english as well as in german!!